# My Application crashes in API level 19 phones and shows error Resource not found but working fine in 22 API level phones

Tags: android

When I am running my android application on API LEVEL 22  its working fine but when I open my android application on API LEVEL 19 its crashes down and showing unfortunately stopped.I am putting the screenshot of my complete logcat to make you properly understand my question

**Here are the xmls**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/zoologo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_white"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zoo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="Ans of Experts"
    android:textColor="#ff00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zoologo"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/signin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign in"
    android:textColor="#ff00"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zoo"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/signin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <customfonts.MyEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="USERNAME"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColorHint="#a9b0c3"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#a9b0c3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        >
    </LinearLayout>

    <customfonts.MyEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="PASSWORD"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="#a9b0c3"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#a9b0c3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="or sign in with:"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ff00"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fb"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnfacebook"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/google"
            android:id="@+id/btngoogle"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twiter"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/btntwitter"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/create"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Don't Have An Account ?"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#ff00"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forgot Password"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#ff00"

        />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is complete logcat log**

> 01-01 10:06:51.614 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419d0c98)
>   01-01 10:06:51.614 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
>   01-01 10:06:51.614 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ali.ansofexperts/com.example.ali.ansofexperts.UserLogin}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class TextView
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   01-01 10:06:51.615 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
>   01-01 10:06:51.616 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-01 10:06:51.616 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class TextView
>   01-01 10:06:51.616 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at com.example.ali.ansofexperts.UserLogin.onCreate(UserLogin.java:59)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5280)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     ... 11 more
>   01-01 10:06:51.617 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0200bb a=-1 r=0x7f0200bb}
>   01-01 10:06:51.618 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2572)
>   01-01 10:06:51.618 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:710)
>   01-01 10:06:51.618 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.view.View.(View.java:3678)
>   01-01 10:06:51.618 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:668)
>   01-01 10:06:51.618 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:74)
>   01-01 10:06:51.618 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:70)
>   01-01 10:06:51.618 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
>   01-01 10:06:51.619 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
>   01-01 10:06:51.619 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
>   01-01 10:06:51.619 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
>   01-01 10:06:51.619 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     ... 22 more
>   01-01 10:06:51.619 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
>   01-01 10:06:51.620 7209-7209/com.example.ali.ansofexperts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.ali.ansofexperts, PID: 7209
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ali.ansofexperts/com.example.ali.ansofexperts.UserLogin}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class TextView
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
>                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class TextView
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                                                                                   at com.example.ali.ansofexperts.UserLogin.onCreate(UserLogin.java:59)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5280)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655) 
>                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0200bb a=-1 r=0x7f0200bb}
>                                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2572)
>                                                                                   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:710)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.(View.java:3678)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:668)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:74)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:70)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                                                                                   at com.example.ali.ansofexperts.UserLogin.onCreate(UserLogin.java:59) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5280) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655) 
>                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**Here is the app level gradle**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
   buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ali.ansofexperts"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
     buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation files('libs/GenAsync.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Post the xml please. Are you using VetorDrawables?

Comment: First, please paste logcat errors as a text. Second, please add your layout's XML file.

Comment: okay i am pasting the logcat error as a text sorry for inconvenience

Comment: What is your minimum sdk version in build gradle

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler im not using VetorDrawables

Comment: @Shivakumar minSdkVersion 19

Comment: Change to less than 19 like 15 and try once

Comment: is there any need to post my depencies of build gradle ????

Comment: @Shivakumar i tried with minSdkVersion 15 but still it behave same

Comment: are you using images in app?

Comment: "are you using images in app " @Shivakumar im not understand what you are asking !

Comment: "android:src="@drawable/ic_white" in your code does ic_white is an image?

Comment: @Shivakumar yes

Comment: save  your images in drawable folder with v24 type

Comment: @Shivakumar done that

Answer (score 0):

One of your drawables is not a `drawable` or `color`:

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0200bb a=-1 r=0x7f0200bb} 01-01`

Probably this one `@drawable/round`.

Comment: Jovanovic  yes this is causing the app to crash but what is the reason behind this and how to solve this problem. The  @drawable/round.xml im using for shape

Comment: after removed @drawable/round same error it showing for Imageview why ???

Comment: @drawable/round and images that giving error are stored  in drawable folder with v21 type

Comment: i cant remove those images and shape because its important.

Comment: Why are they in "drawable-v21" folder? Do you have a version of them in `drawable` folder? And which is the SDK level of your device/emulator on which you are running this app?

Comment: I'm running it on 25 API LEVEL Phone and also I'm running it on 19 API LEVEL phone also. Rather than this I want to know what is the drawable folder version I don't know about this please explain it

Comment: And in which folder do I need to put my shape xml and images

Comment: You can read all about that [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), but that's not part of this question. I can't teach you how to organize resources in your Android project in comments, so please resolve this question.